# How long do cool/hot drinks last?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I fear I may have to make my first trip into the less than savory areas of the Sandy Plains soon, and I want to make sure I'm prepared with enough drinks to last for the duration of my visit. About how long does each individual drink last?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my experience with the first couple of Monster Hunters translates properly, then Hot and Cold Drinks last 10 minutes. Five of them would easily last you the whole hunt, bar any unfortunate accidents (read: giant Tigrex biting your face off).

The armor skill Everlasting increases the duration of these buffs as well as the attack and defense boosts from Demondrug and Armorskins, respectively.

Comment: +1 I just tested this in game, and I can confirm they last for 10 minutes.